# Removing subfloatrow borders in floatrow

Tags: border, floatrow

I have the following code that lays out some images in `subfloatrow`s (I've also set up an [Overleaf project](https://www.overleaf.com/read/fhzryvjdxfgs) with this code for testing purposes):

```
\documentclass{FRIteza}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[subfigure]{capbesideposition={left,center}}

\newlength{\colwidth}
\newlength{\rowheight}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \floatsetup[subfigure]{capbesidewidth=12mm}
    \setlength{\colwidth}{.4\linewidth}
    \setlength{\rowheight}{.75\colwidth}
    \centering
    \ffigbox{%
        \begin{subfloatrow}
            \fcapside[\FBwidth]
            {\caption{Image AB}\label{fig:figurea}}%
            {\hfill\null%
                \includegraphics[width=\colwidth,height=\rowheight]{example-image-a}\hfill%
                \includegraphics[width=1.5\colwidth,height=\rowheight]{example-image-b}\hfill\null%
            }
        \end{subfloatrow}
        \begin{subfloatrow}
          \fcapside[\FBwidth]
            {\caption{Image C}\label{fig:figureb}}%
            {\hfill\null%
                \includegraphics[width=\colwidth,height=\rowheight]{example-image-c}\hfill%
                \includegraphics[width=1.5\colwidth,height=\rowheight]{example-image-c}\hfill\null%
            }
        \end{subfloatrow}
    }%
    {\caption{This is the caption of the entire figure, describing what the figure as a whole is showing in detail and giving an overall picture of the figure's purpose.}\label{fig:figure}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This lays out the images OK:

[image]

However, it puts frames around the subfigures, which doesn't happen when using `subfigure` or other environments to lay out subfigures. I would like to remove the borders around the rows (while keeping the border around the whole figure). I've dug around the class file I'm required to use (`FRIteza.cls`, which can be found in the [Overleaf project](https://www.overleaf.com/read/fhzryvjdxfgs) - unfortunately I don't think I can attach files to the question) and it seems to customize the `floatrow` settings quite a bit. As such, I tried turning the borders off by adding `framearound=none` to the `\floatsetup` inside my figure, following the [`floatrow` docs](https://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/floatrow/floatrow.pdf), but the borders still show up.

Is there a simple way to remove these subrow borders while keeping the border around the figure intact?